# Extreme vertical spacing between lines

Tags: line-spacing

How can I fine tune and reduce the vertical spacing of lines so characters from lines above and below are almost pixel-touching each other?

Example:

[image: Example of lines barely touching each other]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `\offinterlineskip\lineskip1pt` might seem to give the desired result, lines will be irregularly spaced, because the distance between base lines will depend on the presence of ascenders (letters like "d") or descenders (letters like "y"). Moreover not all descenders and ascenders are equal.

Tight typesetting can be obtained by calling, say, `\fontsize{10}{10}` for ten point size. One can get cheaply such a setting by modifying the internal function `\set@fontsize`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\set@fontsize{#3}{#2}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\large\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Only **etoolbox** is required, of course. The patch will substitute the call of the third argument to `\set@fontsize` with the second; the third parameter is indeed the baselineskip and the second is the font size.

Note that this will affect all text at all sizes.

[image]

If only some paragraphs are to be "tightly typeset", then the environment `tight` defined as follows will do the job. The `\addvspace` commands have been used on the assumption that the code is used for examples. Variations on the theme are possible.

```
\makeatletter
\let\tightset@fontsize\set@fontsize
\patchcmd\tightset@fontsize{#3}{#2}{}{}
\newenvironment{tight}
  {\par\addvspace\topsep
   \let\set@fontsize\tightset@fontsize
   \fontsize{\f@size}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont}
  {\par\addvspace\topsep}
\makeatother
```

If tight typesetting is needed for captions, it's simpler. With the **caption** package define the font used by saying something like

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{tight}{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=tight,labelfont=bf}
```

Comment: Indeed, the other answers have the result of irregular spacing when rendered. I thought this cannot be fixed but your answer renders beautifully. Is it possible to use `\set@fontsize` to control and design vertical spacing for lists like my question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23948/extreme-vertical-spacing-between-list-items-nested-lists)? Or is the current selected answer the best way to control vertical height for lists?

Answer (score 8):

`\offinterlineskip` is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
{% Use it LOCALLY
  \offinterlineskip
  \lipsum[2]
}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

You can add `\lineskip=1pt` after `\offinterlineskip`, if the lines are too close.

---

There're mainly three parameters about line spacing: `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit`.

A good explanation of parameters about line spacing, is Chapter 12 (Glue) in TeXbook. Or you can see Chapter 15 (Baseline Distances) in [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic), it said:

- `\baselineskip`:  The ‘ideal’ baseline distance between neighbouring boxes on a vertical
  list. Plain TeX default: `12pt`.
- `\lineskiplimit`:  Distance to be maintained between the bottom and top of neighbouring
  boxes on a vertical list. Plain TeX default: `0pt`.
- `\lineskip`:  Glue added if the distance between bottom and top of neighbouring boxes is
  less than `\lineskiplimit`. Plain TeX default: `1pt`.

In LaTeX, we usually only change `\baselineskip` through `\fontsize` and `\linespread`, `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip` are not often used.

If you want to pry, in [LaTeX kernel](http://ctan.org/pkg/source2e), `\offinterlineskip` is defined as:

```
\def\offinterlineskip{\baselineskip-\@m\p@
  \lineskip\z@ \lineskiplimit\maxdimen}
```

Comment: How do I expand the vertical space a bit if I think it's too squished? What parameter value should I tweak?

Comment: @Level1Coder: In that case, Werner's solution is OK. I suggest `\linespread{0}` instead of `\linespread{0.5}`. I'll add some more information minutes later.

Comment: @Level1Coder: See my update.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX and I really would like to understand every part of example code given here. What does the code within `{% Use it LOCALLY` do? Why is it necessary to have those specific commands in curly brackets?

Comment: Both answers work, in general cases Werner's answer works fine. But in my usage, I really like how there is finer grain control in your method. Modifying your line `\lineskip=0.2pt` in 0.1 increments I can see changes in the final PDF render. Whereas with Werner's `\linespread{0.5}\selectfont`, I only see changes in 0.5 increments. So in my case, yours is the best answer.

Comment: If you want to pry, in plain TeX kernel, the \offinterlineskip is defined equally.

Answer (score 3):

For stretching (or increasing) the line spacing, you can use the [`setspace` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace), or use `\linespread{<factor>}`. Using the latter, the following minimal example showcases some of the effects of changing the `\linespread`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\linespread{0.5}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]
\linespread{2}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Different line spreads]

[Here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespread) is also a short discussion on this topic on the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/about).

Comment: Do not use `\linespread{0.5}\selectfont`. It has no meaning. And for this question, it is not correct for many cases. The right way is to set `\baselineskip` less than `\lineskiplimit`, and set `\lineskip` to 0pt, that's what `\offinterlineskip` do.

Comment: @Leo: Without more context and the minimal requirement specified by the OP, there are many other ways of fulfilling the request, I'm sure.

Comment: In LaTeX, `\lineskip` is 1pt by default. Set small `\baselineskip` will not suffie the request, if the OP really want no space between lines. After all, the default 1pt value of `\lineskip` makes the texts more readable.