# Page number is visible despite a collapsed footer

Tags: page-numbering, geometry, footer

Consider the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[footskip=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

This results in the following pdf rendering (the file's margins were trimmed in the preparation of the image):

[image: nofoot option for geometry package]

To the best of my understanding, supported by [this comment by @Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/define-different-heights-for-head-and-foot#comment19477_10898), the footer's height is determined by the `footskip` option. However, observe that despite setting the `footskip` option to `0pt`, a page number is visible. Doesn't the page number "live" inside the footer?

To press the latter point further, consider the following slightly modified version of the above document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[footskip=-10pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

The pdf rendering of this document is as follows (again, the margins were trimmed in the preparation of the image):

[image: <code>nofoot</code> with a negative <code>footskip</code>]

The image shows that the baseline of the footer is strictly above the bottom of the textarea, and yet the page number appears *below* the textarea. So where does the page number live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clipping done on the head or foot, the box is just overfull if you add content that does not fit

Use

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

if you want no text in the head and foot.

Note that `\footskip` is just a length register than holds a value that is just used to locally set the `\baselineskip` as the box with the footer is added. This means it is the target baseline to baseline spacing, but if it is too small then `\baselineskip` (and so `\footskip` is not used at all and `\lineskip` is used (which is 0pt here).

If you add `\showbox` to the original test document you see the spacing before the footline containing `1`

```
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x430.00462, glue set 212.5023fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
```

Note that it is using `\lineskip` glue which means that `\baselineskip` (which would have been locally set to `\footskip`) is not used here.

Comment: Thanks. However, I still wonder: where does the page number "live"? If you add the option `showframe` to the `geometry` `\usepackage` command, you'll see that the page number appears below the bottom of the textarea, even though the `footskip` option is set to `0pt`, which would imply that the footer's baseline should coincide with the bottom of the textarea. If you additionally change the `footskip` to `-10pt`, this "contradiction" is even more pronounced, since the page number still appears below the text area, even though the footer's baseline is strictly above the bottom of the text area.

Comment: `footskip` is just a distance to the footer saying how much to space it off from the text body.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Hence `footskip=0pt` means that the footer's baseline coincides with the bottom of the textarea, right? Then how come does the page number appear *below* the textarea?

Comment: @EvanAad it is just the same as if you set baselineskip to 0pt, tex does not put every line of the paragraph at the same point over-printing, it just gives up and stacks them vertically with no equalized baseline spacing

Comment: Yes, that is what `source2e` says. But trying this in an `article` it shows that it is to the top of the footer box (e.g. use `geometry` with its `showframe` option)

Comment: `\footskip` is used just in one place, to set `\baselineskip` locally when adding the footer: `\baselineskip \footskip`

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I edited my question to add a `showframe`. This only makes the problem more perplexing.

Comment: David, I've edited my question to add the content of my first comment to your answer.

Comment: @EvanAad the output seems as expected to me, but I'll add some tracing output to my answer.

Comment: @EvanAad answer updated

Comment: Could you please dumb your answer down a little? It's a little too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: @EvanAad see for example this answer on how \lineskip is used if \baselineskip can not be achieved https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/extreme-vertical-spacing-between-lines/23955#23955